# How to add checkbox info to MySQL database using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, checkbox

I have a simple list populated via `MySql` via `Ajax / Json`. The list is just a title and description and every entry has a `checkbox`. I need the `checkbox`, once clicked, to push to database that it is clicked. How would you go about doing that?

[btw...
right now since I have a `setTimeInterval` on my SQL data to deliver the list on the fly it automatically resets my checkbox. I'm assuming that if I record that my `checkbox` has been set via boolean in the SQL that there could be a way to keep it checked...]

I'm new at this and I'm just playing around and trying to learn so this information is entirely theoretical.

Comment: You should provide the code that you're using and your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the on() function to listen to checkbox clicks.

```
$(function() {
    $(document.body).on('click', 'input.mycheckbox', function() {
        var checkbox = $(this);
        var checked = checkbox.attr('checked');
        $.ajax('service.url', {
            type: 'post',
            data: {action: 'checkbox-select', id: checkbox.attr('id'), checked: checked},
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                // Revert
                checkbox.attr('checked', !checked);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Feel free to ask if you need any clarification or if this doesn't fit your situation.

EDIT:

The `data` parameter of the AJAX function is an object that will be posted to your PHP page. When your PHP code is running, `$_POST` will be an array containing the values we passed. So, `$_POST['action']` will be 'checkbox-select', `$_POST['id']` will get the ID, and `$_POST['checked']` will be true or false depending on whether the checkbox was selected or deselected. Your method of getting the ID in the Javascript will probably change; I just put `checkbox.attr('id')` to give you an idea.

When learning PHP it can be helpful to dump the responses from the server on the client-side. Example PHP code:

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'checkbox-select']) {
    $checkbox = $_POST['id'];
    $checked = $_POST['checked'];
    // Your MySQL code here
    echo 'Updated';
}
echo 'Code ran';
```

I edited the JS to show the result from the server.

Comment: service.url??? but I have connection to db stored in php variable. Can I use that?

Comment: @SunRhythms "service.url" is a placeholder for the URL of your PHP page. Replace it with your page URL and your PHP page should be able to read the data from the $_POST array.

Comment: @SunRhythms See my updated response. If you're still having difficulty, you might want to find a tutorial online.

Comment: how can I show you my code? I understand everything but the ajax part... I dont see the "type":"POST", or the $.post

Comment: The thing is the checkbox's Id, name, and attributes all come from the while loop. The user places the information of the title and the description in a form.  I wrote it to attach the name of the title for the checkbox label. The list populates the data from the title. you can see it here.  http://sunrhythms.com/ithtest/fp/

Comment: @SunRhythms Yes, you're right about the post thing. I changed it to post. Alternatively, you can leave it as 'get' and use the `$_GET` array. I would definitely get rid of the setTimeout before you do anything else. It uses bandwidth unnecessarily and makes it hard to use the F12 web inspector (AKA my best friend). If it makes it easier to write your query, you can send the name instead of the ID as long as the name is unique.

Comment: There has to be a way for me to get the results from a while loop and set the [$i] to be used for the checklist. Its the only way it will work.

Comment: @SunRhythms Yes, but I wouldn't do it that way. I really, really recommend you just send the rows that the user changes.